# Why select option value is not selected after clone it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone

I have a select and I want to clone it, then append after it with the same selected option.

HTML

```
<select>
    <option value="0">test0</option>
    <option value="1">test1</option>
    <option value="2">test2</option>
</select>
```

javascript

```
(function($){
$('select').change(function(){
    $clone = $(this).clone();
    $(this).after($clone);
});
})(jQuery)
```

jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/willHsu/3tRR9/

The way I find is to use

```
var value = $(this).children('option:selected').val();
```

to find the value then choose as a selected option.
So I know the way to solve it.

but I still wonder why `clone()` method can't copy the selected option status?
can anyone give me a reasonable explanation?

Comment: Because: "**Note:** For performance reasons, the dynamic state of certain form elements (e.g., user data typed into textarea and user selections made to a select) is not copied to the cloned elements. When cloning input elements, the dynamic state of the element (e.g., user data typed into text inputs and user selections made to a checkbox) is retained in the cloned elements." From the API documentation for [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).

Comment: The same thing happens without jquery, using straight javascript.  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33pzf/)

Comment: @David Thomas Thanks for your clear comment．